# Instant table filtering in GWT

Tags: gwt, flextable

I would like to do a kind of table (maybe FlexTable) and be able to apply a filter (any String)and instantly remove rows which don't contain that String. I have checked similar questions, but they are very old (3-4 years ago).

You can see an example in datatables plugin for jquery: http://www.datatables.net/

I just need the filter, so I think I can do it using a TextBox and KeyPressHandler to detect pressed keys, and only show rows which contain the input text when input.length()>=3.

Anyone has a better idea or approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend using a `CellTable` or  a `DataGrid`. With these you can associate a `ListDataProvider` in which you can put all of the logic for filtering.

You should create your own implementation of `DataListProvider` where you pass in a `String` or a custom `Filter` if you want more complex filtering. You need to create
`filter(String filterExpression)` and call it from your table whenever you want to filter the rows.

```java
public class MyListDataProvider<T> extends DataListProvider<T>{

    public void filter(String filterExpression){

         // Here you filter your local list containing the data use
         List<T> list = getList();

         ...

         // Refresh all of the objects associated to this ListDataProvider
         refresh();

    }

}
```

You can keep an extra `List<T>` containing all of the items without any filtering so that you can access filtered out items when you want to "unfilter" or change the filter expression.

This method will be much more efficient than using a `FlexTable` since with the `FlexTable` you would have to go through each row and cell individually. Too many manipulations.